# ActiveMQ Artemis CLI tool says port is in use

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm running ActiveMQ Artemis 2.14.0. Today I tried using the CLI tool inside the broker's `bin` folder, but it gives me an error that port `9876` is in use. This happens even for the `help` command. I checked this port, and the user running Artemis has it. I also see an empty `cli.lock` file in the broker's `lock` folder.

I'm trying to add a new user to the broker. Does this mean the broker needs to be shut down to add a user, or otherwise access the CLI? Here is the error:

```
WARNING: Failed to instantiate LoggerFinder provider; Using default.
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9876; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9876; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:491)
        at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
        at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9876; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:220)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:180)
        at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.SingleEntryRegistry.<init>(SingleEntryRegistry.java:49)
        at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:836)
        at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:479)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:452)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:149)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324)
        ... 11 more
```

Here's my `etc/artemis.profile`:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

ARTEMIS_HOME='/opt/artemis-2.14.0'
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE='/var/lib/broker-HA'
ARTEMIS_DATA_DIR='/var/lib/broker-HA/data'
ARTEMIS_ETC_DIR='/var/lib/broker-HA/etc'
ARTEMIS_OOME_DUMP='/var/lib/broker-HA/log/oom_dump.hprof'

# The logging config will need an URI
# this will be encoded in case you use spaces or special characters
# on your directory structure
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_URI='file:/var/lib/broker-HA/'
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI='file:/var/lib/broker-HA/etc/'

# Cluster Properties: Used to pass arguments to ActiveMQ Artemis which can be referenced in broker.xml
#ARTEMIS_CLUSTER_PROPS="-Dactivemq.remoting.default.port=61617 -Dactivemq.remoting.amqp.port=5673 -Dactivemq.remoting.stomp.port=61614 -Dactivemq.remoting.hornetq.port=5446"


# Java Opts
if [ -z "$JAVA_ARGS" ]; then
    JAVA_ARGS=" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9876 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[ip] -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Xms512M -Xmx2G -Dhawtio.realm=activemq  -Dhawtio.offline=true -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=${ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI}jolokia-access.xml"
fi

#
# Logs Safepoints JVM pauses: Uncomment to enable them
# In addition to the traditional GC logs you could enable some JVM flags to know any meaningful and "hidden" pause that could
# affect the latencies of the services delivered by the broker, including those that are not reported by the classic GC logs
# and dependent by JVM background work (eg method deoptimizations, lock unbiasing, JNI, counted loops and obviously GC activity).
# Replace "all_pauses.log" with the file name you want to log to.
# JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=all_pauses.log"

#
# Enables the dumping of the java heap when a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception is thrown.
# JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_ARGS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=${ARTEMIS_OOME_DUMP}"

# Debug args: Uncomment to enable debug
#DEBUG_ARGS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"

# Debug args: Uncomment for async profiler
#DEBUG_ARGS="-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints"
```

Comment: The broker does not need to be stopped to use the CLI. Port `9876` is typically used by the broker for multicast UDP in clustered configurations. However, from the stack-trace it appears something related to JMX is configured to use port `9876` in your environment. Can you paste your `etc/artemis.profile`?

Comment: I see I have this in the $JAVA-ARGS in artemis.profile
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9876

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using? Is that your _full_ `artemis.profile`?

Comment: I missed part of it cutting from the terminal added now. This is 2.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broker does not need to be stopped to use the CLI. Port `9876` is typically used by the broker for multicast UDP in clustered configurations.

The problem is that you've added this to your `$JAVA_ARGS` in `artemis.profile`:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9876 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.40.50.16
```

This will start a JMX connector service listening for remote connections on port `9876` *every* time you use the `artemis` command. You have a few different ways to fix this.

The **best** way to fix this is to remove all these system properties and use the broker-managed JMX connector service which is configured in `etc/management.xml`. Allowing the broker to manage the JMX connector allows it to enforce role-based access control which is important in many deployment scenarios. Your current configuration allows unauthenticated access via JMX which is *strongly* discouraged. Anybody on the network could delete your messages, stop the broker, etc.

You could change `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port` to use something other than `9876`.

You could also modify `artemis.profile` so that these settings are only applied for the `run` command (i.e. running the broker). The [latest versions of `artemis.profile`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/artemis-cli/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/artemis/cli/commands/etc/artemis.profile#L56) already do this for debug related settings.

Lastly, I strongly recommend that you upgrade to the [latest version of ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/). Version 2.14.0 was released over 3 years ago now. There have been thousands of commits to the code-base since then to fix bugs, add new features, etc. Perhaps most notably, a new [interactive shell](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-cli.html#artemis-shell) was added in the most recent release which makes using the CLI much easier.